# JavaScript Reset a dropdown to it's default option

Tags: javascript, dropdown, html-select

I have the following dropdown in HTML:

```
<div class="drop-down-container">
      <span>Select Employee: </span>
      <select
        class="drop-down"
        id="employees-list"
        onchange="populateTable();"
      >
        <option selected disabled>--Select--</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

And the JS which populates the dropdown with a list of employees:

```
// Loop through all employees and display them on the dropdown
    for (var i = 0; i < getResources.length; i++) {
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = getResources[i].children[1].textContent;
      empList.options.add(option);
      option.value = getResources[i].children[0].innerHTML;
    }
```

I want to clear all the data in the dropdown and default to the base HTML version with the --Select-- option, I'm currently using the following:

```
const empList = document.getElementById("employees-list");

    while (empList.firstChild) {
      empList.removeChild(empList.firstChild);
    }
```

This works great but it clears all the data in the dropdown and throws the first value as the default which leads to the onchange function not executing and thus I have to pick another value and then back to the first one before it triggers. I don't know which will be easier, getting a workaround to letting the first value load immediately as the data populates the dropdown or change the loop so it removes everything except the default value. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please show what is inside - `getResources`

Comment: The getResources is just a variable which returns a list of employees using getElementsByTagName value which comes from a soap web service

Comment: *This works great but it clears all the data in the dropdown and throws the first value as the default which leads to the onchange function not executing and thus I have to pick another value and then back to the first one before it triggers* Could you please elaborate the intent here. This is bit obscure.

Comment: once the new data is loaded, the onchange function does not trigger, which leads to the employee's data not displaying on the table, and then you have to first select someone else on the list then the first person for their data to load, the change of employees trigger the onchange function but not when they're loaded in.